# Accessing information stored within credentials.yml.enc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, credentials

I am currently trying to access information which is stored in my `credentials.yml.enc` file

When I run `Rails console`, I get the expected value returned for `Rails.application.credentials.email_password`

I would now like to read this same value into `db_backup.rb`, which contains the line (I am currently running the code on my local development machine)

`mail.password = Rails.application.credentials.email_password`

However, the following error is raised:

`NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Backup::Config::DSL:0x00007fb0db941d10>>::Rails`

**Please could you inform me how this statement should be adjusted when within a .rb file, or if there is something I should be doing before this command?**

I have read a number of guides, including those below which are generally useful, however they don't appear to provide this information:

https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

https://blog.eq8.eu/til/rails-52-credentials-tricks.html

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

The structure of my `db_backup.rb` file is:

```
Model.new(:db_backup, 'Description for db_backup') do

  ##
  # PostgreSQL [Database]
  #
  database PostgreSQL do |db|
    # To dump all databases, set `db.name = :all` (or leave blank)
    db.name               = "my_db_name"
    db.username           = Rails.application.credentials.production[:username]
    db.password           = Rails.application.credentials.production[:password]
    db.host               = "localhost"
    db.port               = 5432
    db.socket             = "/tmp"
    # When dumping all databases, `skip_tables` and `only_tables` are ignored.
    # db.skip_tables        = ["skip", "these", "tables"]
    # db.only_tables        = ["only", "these", "tables"]
    # db.additional_options = ["-xc", "-E=utf8"]
  end
end
```

**Having seen a number of tutorials online, it appears the syntax above should be correct, however, I guess I must be putting this in the wrong place in the code?  Any guidance would be great**

Thanks in advance

Comment: This line did you tried to switch to development environment?  Rails.application.credentials.development[:username] Rails.application.credentials.development[:password]

Comment: Yes and I have also tried using a non-nested variable e.g.  `Rails.application.credentials.username`  and ``Rails.application.credentials[:username]`.  All give the same error

Comment: thats the demo project can you push it to github so  I can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of use to others, it turned out that I simply had to add the line `require './config/environment'` to the top of my `db_backup.rb` file

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried read credentials like in this sample:

Reading credentials
Let’s assume that the unencrypted version of your `config/credentials.yml.enc` file looks like this:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: 123
  secret_access_key: 345
  secret_key_base: 2fdea1259c6660852864f9726616df64c8cd
```

Then, you should be able to access the configuration programmatically like this:

```
Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]     # => "123"
Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key] # => "345"
Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base         # => "2fdea...
```

In your case you should get email password in line like this:

```
Rails.application.credentials.somerootelementinyourfile[:email_password]
```

You see aws: is root element in `config/credentials.yml.enc` sample, so I think you should have something similar if not try some combining.

More information you can find here: https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes this is exactly one of the things I tried - this works successfully in the Rails console, but errors if you put it in the `db_backup.rb` file.  Is there something I need to initiate first before running this line, or is it likely to be linked to the encryption?  I tried hardcoding a value, rather than trying to read from the `credentials.yml.enc` file and this worked fine.

Comment: how does looks your db_backup.rb?

Comment: Exactly as per the auto-generated format (http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/generator/) with initially a single line replaced as described above:  `mail.password = Rails.application.credentials.email_password `

Comment: what about if you just put some strings on place of this line? do you still have db_backup error? I am thinking like maybe you have problem in your db_backup.rb file on some other lines, or in using calling this file? If you get values from console I dont see any problem why woudnt see anywhere except you dont have any other error because format of that file or some wrong value in config of that file ....

Comment: also did you checked this part of medium link above:  If you are upgrading your app, and not starting from a brand new Rails 5.2 app, make sure to add the following configuration to your config/environments/production.rb file:

config.require_master_key = true
This will tell Rails to ensure that a master key has been made available from either ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'] or in config/master.key.

Comment: If I just pass the value directly as a string, the line of code runs successfully.  I built the app from scratch in Rails 5.2 and have confirmed that `config.require_master_key = true `.  My guess is that there is some line that I need to put in before this statement along the lines of `db_config           = YAML.load_file('/var/www/phindee/shared/config/database.yml')['production']` as described in http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/06/30/backup-a-rails-database-with-the-backup-and-whenever-gems/

Comment: if its a demo site can you maybe upload it to github so I can check it on my dev pc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181181/discussion-between-texas-and-nezir).

Comment: I have updated the question with details of my `db_backup.rb`, hardcoding the values works perfectly, trying to pull a just a single parameter from the credentials.yml.enc causes the original error